# Automatically mute speakers when headphones are unplugged

Tags: audio, headphones

I was wondering if there is a "software" solution to automatically mute the laptop speakers when the headphones are "unplugged"?

OS : Windows XP SP3
Laptop : Dell Vostro 1510
Audio Drivers : RealTek

Please provide software solutions only. I don't want to buy any additional hardware to achieve this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? Don't most people want the opposite?

Comment: I like listening to music in the office, and sometimes the headphone wire gets unplugged accidentally. As a result, people around get disturbed. I want to avoid that.

Comment: I did find a software ryanharter.com/index.htm, but it is for MAC only

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling your Vostro audio drivers and installing the generic Microsoft drivers. Microsoft's driver allows you to create multiple "audio profiles" which let you have different sound configurations depending on what audio devices are plugged in. You may also want to check if your current audio driver supports this feature first before making any changes.

Comment: @ John T : Your solution works and I will use it as the last resort. But, I am looking for a piece of software that can provide me this functionality without me having to uninstall/reinstall drivers. 
Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: I'm pretty sure something like this (detecting hardware being removed) can only be handled at the driver level. I will take another look though.

Comment: It's at the hardware level, but most modern hardware has that capability. In Vista and 7, you have separate profiles for headphones and speakers (you can configure the audio level separately, and it automatically detects when you've plugged your headphones in or out).

Comment: I did find a software http://ryanharter.com/index.htm, but it is for MAC only :(

Comment: Hey John - I tried your workaround above (on my Lenovo Thinkpad T500 on Windows 7) but my Conexant drivers were just reinstalled by Windows Update and I couldn't find "generic microsoft drivers". I also couldn't find any mention of the "audio profiles" feature. Any idea where I can get ahold of those generic drivers?